# Odoo 13, how to upload the contents of my Postgres Database on GITHUB

Tags: postgresql, github, odoo-13

**I'am starter on Odoo and I'm trying to upload the contents of my database on Github.**

Indeed, I was asked to install Odoo 13 on my local Ubuntu 18.04 machine (which has already been done) then to push the contents of the Odoo 13 installation on a GITHUB repository with the contents of its database.

This must be done in such a way that when I perform an operation on my local which is linked to a branch of my repository the changes I made are sent there (for example, changing the company logo to local ) and on the server side, I get what was pushed on GITHUB from the local to the remote server.

**So To sum up:**

- **I have my local machine** on which I work and make the modifications;
- **The GITHUB repository** to which these modifications are sent (*for example modification: Change of the logo, the photo of a user or even the creation of a company*);
- **The Remote server** on which I retrieve the contents of the GITHUB repository with all modifications made locally;

***My problem is when sending the content of my Odoo installation to GITHUB as well as the content of its database.***

**Thanks for your Help!**

Comment: Try the tools ```pg_dump``` and ```pg_restore``` coming with your ```PostgreSQL``` installations. Then you could pass the dump-files between your machines. Anyway, this sounds undesirable... If you need to add/update any entries in your database for new features, you should have a look at migrations. This is the standard way. And the migrations are then just part of your codebase and you can work with them as with all your other code via Git

Comment: But migrations are used to switch from one version to another, right?

Comment: Yes, this is right. Why do you want to sync your local and remote database? If you do "production" work, do it on the remote. A local database is usually only for development/testing and you do not need (and most of the time also do not want) to have the testing data in your production environment (what I believe your remote server is meant to be). You only want structural changes of the local DB also to be applied to the remote DB on version upgrades and this is what migrations are for. If this does not help you, perhaps tell us a bit more about your use case, why do you need all local data?

Comment: I need all local data because I'm not allow to work directly on the remote server.
Went I commit from my local, it is subject to a validate and my superiors try to keep a history of my activities which is why I have to go through GITHUB.

Comment: I still do not really understand this... You are doing your work locally, push it to Github, your boss pulls it, reloads the DB, checks the entries, and then they pass it to production? Sounds a little weird to me...
But if you really need to provide all data from the local DB to those who pull from this Github project, you should be able to dump the DB using ```pg_dump``` and add this to your repository

Comment: Yess you are right it working like that but, if I make many `pg_dump` I will have many Odoo's Instances on my server. I wouldn't like to have it like this.

Is it possible to have automatic `backup update`, to say when I push an *Odoo Dump* in GITHUB or on my server **it automaticaly update the old running database**.